# Getting insert id with RxJava (Room)

Tags: java, rx-java, android-room

I can add a row using RxJava with the following,

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> db.userDao().insert(user)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }
        });
```

Dao:

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    long insert(User user);
```

How can I get the row id after the DB operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use RxJava with Room you can change the `insert` function to return RxJava Single wrapping a `Long`, like:

```
@Insert
Single<Long> insert(User user);
```

This way you can just subscribe to this `Single` and you'll get the id as Long with something like this:

```
db.userDao().insert(user)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new SingleObserver<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Long aLong) {
                // aLong is the id
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
            }
        });
```

Comment: Could you please tell me the 'import' you use for the Single? I am having troubles as you can see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67063811/error-when-returning-singlelong-using-room-insert-method?noredirect=1#comment118541314_67063811