# How to return id after saving a record room using RxJava + MVVM

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I'm developing an android app with Kotlin.
I'm using RxJava and MVVM.

i tried this :
[a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043437/getting-insert-id-with-rxjava-room)

Here is one of my method in DataSource interface

```
fun insertPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: PhoneNumber) : Long

    fun insertAllPhoneNumber(phoneNumberList: List<PhoneNumber>): List<Long>
```

The question is, after building the basic classes and requirements.
The compiler issues an error as follows:

```
  e: [kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
  long cannot be converted to an Element
```

I want to return the corresponding ID when a record is stored in my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using RxJava your Dao interface should look like this...

```
@Dao
interface WhateverDao {

    @Insert
    fun insertPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: PhoneNumber) : Maybe<Long>

    @Insert
    fun insertAllPhoneNumber(vararg phoneNumberList: PhoneNumber): Maybe<List<Long>>
}
```

Changes are:

- Mark the interface with `@Dao`
- Mark insert methods with `@Insert`
- Pass a `vararg` to the insert all method
- Use RxJava classes on the return type to make use of the reactive-streams pattern

Comment: **Now error is : **
```
 error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
    public abstract io.reactivex.Flowable<java.util.List<java.lang.Long>> insertAllContact(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
                                                                          ^
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot `Flowable` is not support for inserts. Change it to a `Maybe` as in the answer (edited)

Comment: I read this article but still have the problem
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757